# ignore Facebook mobile browser detection

Tags: facebook, mobile, detect

I've made a page tab for a client page on facebook. However, Page tabs are not available via the mobile site (m.facebook.com) which the user is automatically redirected if following the link on a mobile device (i.e. iPhone).

How do I ignore the facebook mobile detection and point the user to the desktop website regardless.

Thanks for any help.

Best,
Jose

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15860533/121285

Answer (score 0):

You don't; if you want to send the user somewhere different depending on whether they're on mobile or not you'll need to implement that yourself and only send users to Facebook when they're on full browsers

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `?m2w` parameter to your link. `m2w` means `mobile to web`.
Post a link to your page if you want me to try it.